# Implementing Controllers and ControllerProviders in a Bolt Extension

Tags: controller, silex, bolt-cms

I'm currently trying to implement a controller within a Bolt (v2.0.6) extension that can handle the post request for a page, I have the following classes.

**Extension.php**

```
namespace MyPlugin;

class Extension extends \Bolt\BaseExtension {

    function initialize()
    {   
        $this->app->mount('/contact', new MyPlugin\Controllers\ContactControllerProvider);   
    }
```

**ContactController.php**

```
namespace MyPlugin\Controllers;

class ContactController
{
    public function store() 
    { 
        // handle the POST request
        exit('store');
    }
```

**ContactControllerProvider.php**

```
namespace MyPlugin\Controllers;

use Silex\Application;
use Silex\ControllerProviderInterface;

class ContactControllerProvider implements ControllerProviderInterface
{
    public function connect(Application $app)
    {   
        // creates a new controller based on the default route
        $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];

        // attempting to add POST hook
        $controllers->post("/", "MyPlugin\Controllers\ContactController::store");

        return $controllers;
    }
}
```

I know that the `ContactControllerProvider` is being instantiated because I can `exit()` during the `connect()` function and that outputs to the browser. However, I can't seem to get the `store()` function in `ContactController` to fire. I also tried with `$contollers->get()` and had the same result.

I appear to have either done something wrong, or missing something out complete. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I approach it.

**Extension.php**

```
namespace MyPlugin;

class Extension extends \Bolt\BaseExtension {

    function initialize()
    {   
        $this->app->mount('/contact', new MyPlugin\Controllers\ContactController());   
    }
}
```

**Controllers\ContactController.php**

```
namespace MyPlugin\Controllers;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Silex\Application;
use Silex\ControllerProviderInterface;

class ContactController implements ControllerProviderInterface
{
    public function connect(Application $app)
    {   
        /** @var $ctr \Silex\ControllerCollection */
        $ctr = $app['controllers_factory'];

        // This matches both GET requests.
        $ctr->match('', [$this, 'show'])
            ->method('GET');

        // This matches POST requests.
        $ctr->match('', [$this, 'store'])
            ->method('POST');

        return $ctr;
    }

    public function show(Application $app, Request $request)
    {
        return new Response('Hello, World!');
    }

    public function store(Application $app, Request $request)
    {
        return new Response('It was good to meet you!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Nearly works. The problem I seem to be having is that I also have contact as a page and have the routing setup so that the `pages` content type doesn't need to be in the URL. So I think the page binding route is trumping this listener.

Comment: Kind of really depends on what precisely you're trying to achieve. My response assumes that a contact for is an example of what you're doing and answering based on that. If you're just doing a contact form, you might get better results and less code you need to worry about using BoltForms.

Comment: Ugh… damn enter key…

That said, if you're trying to stack routes, priority wins. So if you can't get away with having two route the same in Silex/Symfony. What you can do is have a single route apply logic in a controller, or in Twig to handle differing requests to the same route.

Basically having a look at how forms are handled I think lays the answer to what you're trying to get done… just not 100% sure what the objective is yet :-)

Comment: Yeah, I've used Bolt forms before. But this is a quick project so I'm basically wanting to just hardcode the form.. catch the data parse it... send it to an email. I got the impression somewhere that with `Silex` you could specify the `method` for the route in the `.yml` file. So you could specify `GET` and `POST` and target different controllers/actions.

Comment: Ah, right! Yes, I have split the above example's match() functions to show that.